# Why does MySQL leap from version 5.7 to 8.0?

Tags: mysql

I recently upgraded **MySQL 5.7** to **8.0** via homebrew, as it warned me about not being the latest version. I was surprised to see **MySQL** was version **8.0** as from what I recall the latest version was **5.7**. Then I found out there are no **6** and **7** versions which also seems a bit odd.

I struggle to find any relevant or official explanation regarding why it sees this gigantic leap to version **8.0** and skipping right over **6** and **7**. 
While it may be just a convention, this myopic version management only confuses users without any reason why when needing some simple clarification.

So why does the MySQL version numbers see such a leap and skip over 6 and 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### MySQL 5.7 to 8.0 Skipping 6 and 7

Official Oracle answer per [MySQL 8.0 FAQ: General](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-general.html). . .

> ### [Why did MySQL version numbering skip versions 6 and 7 and go straight to 8.0?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-general.html#faq-mysql-why-8.0)
>
> "Due to the many new and important features we were introducing in
>   this MySQL version, we decided to start a fresh new series. As the
>   series numbers 6 and 7 had actually been used before by MySQL, we went
>   to 8.0."

For the people that wonder what's up with the bogus **MySQL 6.0** that was once announced. . .

> ### [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)
>
> "MySQL Server 6.0.11-alpha was **announced on 22 May 2009** as the last
>   release of the 6.0 line. Future MySQL Server development uses a New
>   Release Model. Features developed for 6.0 are being incorporated into
>   future releases."
>
> "In April 2009, Oracle Corporation entered into an agreement to purchase Sun Microsystems, then owners of MySQL copyright and trademark. Sun's board of directors unanimously approved the deal. It was also approved by Sun's shareholders, and by the U.S. government on **20 August 2009.** On 14 December 2009, Oracle pledged to continue to enhance MySQL as it had done for the previous four years."
>
> "MySQL Server 8.0 was announced in **April 2018**, including NoSQL Document
>   Store, atomic and crash safe DDL sentences and JSON Extended syntax,
>   new functions, such as JSON table functions, improved sorting, and
>   partial updates. Previous MySQL Server 8.0.0-dmr (Milestone Release)
>   was announced 12 September 2016."

Comment: [MySQL 6.0](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/mysql-refman-6.0/introduction.html#mysql-nutshell) already exists.

Comment: So what does this mean for all the users of the old 5.7?  Do we all need to upgrade to 8?

Comment: @fja3omega You don't have to upgrade from 5.7 if you don't want to. It appears MySQL 8.0 is still in Beta being developed. 5.7 is the latest non-beta release right now. I suggest once 8.0 goes non beta, get your test system up and start testing if upgrading to 8.0 is a necessity but unless some vendor of some product, etc. tells you to upgrade for support, compatibility, etc. you don't need to upgrade and 5.7 is still supported and at the moment the latest non-beta release.

Comment: *"the bogus MySQL 6.0 that was once announced"* - It's like PHP all over again.